Overriding xsd complex type with simple String in jaxb bindings
I am having a WSDL which I must use and not modify.
In the WSDL there is a type 'TextType' defined without any elements. This 'TextType' is actually meant as simple String (which is only described in a separate documentation file)
  <xs:complexType name="TextType">
  </xs:complexType>

TextType is then used in XSD file as usual:
    <xs:complexType name="AnschriftType">
      <xs:element name="Strasse" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

I know, this WSDL is not really usable nor a good design. The provider of this WSDL already changed it in a newer version. But anyway I have to stick on that faulty version :-/
From this JXB generates theses Pojos:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TextType")
public class TextType {
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AnschriftType" propOrder={...})
public class AnschriftType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Strasse")
    protected TextType strasse;

    public TextType getStrasse() {
        return strasse;
    }

    public void setStrasse(TextType value) {
        this.strasse = value;
    }
}

Is it somehow possible to let JAXB generate the Pojos with 'String' instead of 'TextType'?
I already tried something but didn't work so far...
1)
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='TextType']">
        <jaxb:class name="String" implClass="java.lang.String"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AnschriftType" propOrder={...})
public class AnschriftType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Strasse", type = java.lang.String.class)
    protected java.lang.String strasse;

    public package.of.xsd.String getStrasse() {
        return strasse;
    }

    public void setStrasse(package.of.xsd.String value) {
        this.strasse = ((java.lang.String) value);
    }
}




    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='TextType']">
        <jaxb:property>
            <jaxb:baseType name="java.lang.String"/>
        </jaxb:property>
    </jaxb:bindings>

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AnschriftType" propOrder={...})
public class AnschriftType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Strasse")
    protected TextType strasse;

    public TextType getStrasse() {
        return strasse;
    }

    public void setStrasse(TextType value) {
        this.strasse = value;
    }
}


Could you create MRE with this ? Thanks

What do you mean with "MRE"?

Sorry : Minimal Reproductible Example

Hi @LaurentSchoelens. Sorry for the delay. Here ist the MRE :-) https://github.com/sentinel0815/xsd-texttype
